# dotnet core applications have very slow internet access when running on local machine

Tags: .net, webclient

When dotnet core applications are run from my local machine, they have extremely slow internet access.  For example, if I create an application using `dotnet new console`, and add the following code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            var w = new WebClient();
            var x = w.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Google:" + x);
        }
    }
```

My program takes **23 seconds** to complete, even though the "start" message appears almost straight away.  This occurs with classes other than `WebClient` as well.  However, I can access Google through my web browser almost instantly.  Also, the problem does not occur if I deploy my application (e.g. I am developing ASP.net core applications on AWS Lambda).

Why are the requests taking so long?

EDIT: Futher observations reveal strange things.  Accessing https://agilemanifesto.org/ works instantly, but the [OIDC config for my identity provider](https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_FR9pe6SNy/.well-known/openid-configuration) (which is what I'm actually trying to fetch) takes **1 minute 5 seconds**, which is preposterous.  I'm not yet sure what the difference between them is.

Comment: I have tested your code on local env. it works right a way and fine.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ your original (deleted) suggestion has yielded some other results, see edit

Comment: I am going in sleeping mode now if not solve for you will look at it tomorrow

Comment: sweet dreams hun xoxo